# Visual Studio Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement not working. Error AuthorizationManager check failed

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, runspace

I am trying to run my code from Visual Studio. Code is to create runspace and connect Exchange Online to run PowerShell script. Initial line of script is

```
if (Get-Module -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'ExchangeOnlineManagement'}) {
      Write-Host ""Module ExchangeOnlineManagement is not imported, but available on disk. Importing it. ""
      Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
}
```

On executing it is giving error

```
AuthorizationManager check failed.The 'Connect-ExchangeOnline' command was found in the module 'ExchangeOnlineManagement', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement'
```

Can anyone help to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Create web job instead of console app.

It is resolved now. The problem was with Console App.
When I created a new web job application same code works well.

This **AuthorizationManager check failed** error comes when you try to run this PowerShell script in console app. This error is not coming in web job and connected to Exchange online successfully.